# Poisson problem I think..

Tags: probability

On average, one person enters a casino every 10 minutes. Determine:
a) The probability that no person will enter the casino between 12:00 and 12:30.
b) The probability that at least 4 people enter the casino between 12:00 and 12:30.

What I've tried:
We know that, on average, one person enters a casino every 10 minutes $\implies$ on average, 3 persons enters in casino every 30 minutes $\implies \lambda = 3$. We have a random variable $X \sim Poisson(3)$.

a) $\mathbb{P}(X=0) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{e^3}$

b) $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 4) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X < 4) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 3) = 1-e^{-\lambda}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{3}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!}$.

Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your work is correct.  The intensity of arrivals is $\lambda = 3$ per half hour, so in any given half hour interval, the probability that there are exactly $X$ arrivals is Poisson distributed with intensity $\lambda$, and the desired probabilities are $\Pr[X = 0]$ and $\Pr[X \ge 4]$, respectively, where $$\Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}.$$